# Integrating functions containing both algebraic and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

I have come across several such problems, and have no idea how to proceed. I'll take the example of a 'simple' one:

$$\int\frac{1+\cos x}{x + \sin x}dx$$

The only problem here is the presence of the $x$ in the denominator. How would I proceed with this question? As any trigonometric substitution doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: You have been lucky with the $1$ in the numerator. Remove it and no solution. Replace $1$ by $2$ and no solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{d(x+\sin x)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: Hmmm.... That's why this was simple.

Comment: But is there a general pattern I should follow when I'm given both algebraic and trigonometric functions to integrate? Or will they always have some obvious clue hidden in them?

Comment: @Gummybears, The integration won't be basic if the denominator involves both and no such hidden clue